# drawing a non symmetric table in latex

Tags: tables

Hello every one I need to draw a table like this [image: table]

would be very helpful if anyone could guide.
best regards

Answer (score 2):

Use `multicolumn` for horizontal cells spanning more than one column and `multirow` for cells spanning more than one row:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\cline{2-3}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}        & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{something} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{something}  & something      & something      \\ \cline{2-3}
                            & something      & something      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]